# submit form on a dynamic link

Tags: html, ajax, forms, jsp

Here is the code below which i am using to submit my form. When i click the link, the new window is behaving as current window and the Current window is behaving as new action link. How can i stop this behaviour.

I am reading the linkURL in a java class from JVM parameters.

```
<form action="<c:out value='${config.linkURL}'/>" method="GET" id="myForm">
    <a href="#" target="_blank" id="myLink"><bean:message key="link.cardholder.info"/></a>
    <input type="hidden" name="cardID" value="<c:out value="${config.homeSwitch}"/>" />
    <script>
         $('#myLink').on('click', function() { window.open('<c:out value="${config.linkURL}"/>',"title").focus();});
    </script>
</form>
```

when i tried here the hidden values are not passing along with the url because of not calling submit() function. Any possible way to call submit function.

Comment: you can do it by AJAX post of your form. After successfully of your form submission. you can open a new tab.

Comment: Maybe something else also listening to your form submit event.You may want to use `event.preventDefault();` Add this in your click event callback function.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Answer (score 0):

[This link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement) will provide you with detailed info about the `HTMLFormElement`.

[This link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) will explain what the `submit` method of the `HTMLFormElement` is.

Something like:

```
myForm.submit();
```